# How to fix the width of Label using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix width for the labels according to bootstrap 12 columns. How to make this across 12 columns with following settings with different devices. Please help

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div style="height: 30px; margin: 0; padding: 3">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="tblHeader"
                    style="background-color: #336666; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Employee Name"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Company"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Department"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Designation"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Active"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblOption" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Option"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make it on jsfiddle so we can check what's wrong... (without asp)

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap table should be the th element that lead the width

```
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div style="height: 30px; margin: 0; padding: 3">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all" border="1" id="tblHeader"
                  style="background-color: #336666; color: white; border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%;">
                  <tr>
                      <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                         your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                      <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
                          your column title
                      </th>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="ID"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Employee Name"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Company"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Department"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Designation"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="Label6" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Active"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                      <td >
                          <asp:Label ID="lblOption" CssClass="control-label" runat="server" Text="Option"></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: OK but I want to use my label as Headings. This is actually a fixed header row of GridView Control. I put this in separate page for checking the width of labels. If I use <th> instead of Labels, the result is same as Labels.

Comment: For the label you can use what you prefer .. and for the table you should remove row and form group .. i have update the answer

Comment: Actually, I just replace Table tag with following and it works. <table id="tblHeader" class="table table-condensed"
                                         style="background-color:#336666; color:white;
                                         border-collapse:collapse;height:100%;">